# Using string id for notification or converting string id to generate unique int id

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

In my app I have groups and for each group there can be updates which I am showing in notification. But in database I have group ids as `string`. So for generating notification for each group, I need a unique `int` id. So how can I transform `string` ids to `int` ids. So that there can be only 1 notification per group and the contents can be appended as there are updates in that specific group.

I have seen while displaying notifications I can supply **`tag`** as well.

> NotificationManager.notify(String tag, int id, Notification notification)

But for that I also need to supply `int` id. So how this in combination works? Or any way I can rely only on the `string` id of the notification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `(tag, id)` combination of notifications to be shown differently should be different. Otherwise the latest one will replace the previous one. So, here you can just use the `string id` you have as `tag` if it is unique and use any int `id` as the combination must be unique.

Ref : (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.app.Notification)

Comment: Aha! That's the interesting one. I'll try without int id or with `0`

Comment: With same int id say `0` it worked! thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the hash of the string.  Or you can use the tag for a string.

Comment: A hash will also contain string characters. What do you mean by tag for a string?

Comment: No it won't.  I mean the hashCode, the result of the hashCode function.  Its a mapping from Object->long.  Its what Java uses for a key in hashMaps and the like.

Comment: Ohh! I didn't checked that. I though hashCode will return string of something md5 or sha-1! Thanks for pointing that out.